# jQuery accordion on hover instead of click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the accordion works on hover instead of clicking it i tried some code but everytimes all div with `.panel-collapse` visible at once and not worked properly.

Please somebody fix my codes if possible.

```js
 function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find("i.indicator")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);  
 
 
/**####### COde I tried for onmouseover function #######**/
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#accordion a.accordion-toggle').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('collapsed').closest('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
    })
 $('#accordion a.accordion-toggle').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).addClass('collapsed');
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
     
    
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     

  <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Food <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
   
    <ul class="arrow cate list-unstyled">
 
                 <li><a class="" href="#">1914 translation by H. Rackham</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a></li>
                    
 </ul>
   
   
   
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--loop ends here-->
  
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
          Tourist Spot <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
    
 
  <ul class="arrow cate list-unstyled">
 
                 <li><a class="" href="#">1914 translation by H. Rackham</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a></li>
                    
 </ul>
 
 
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
         Weekend Gateway  <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
    
 <ul class="arrow cate list-unstyled">
 
                 <li><a class="" href="#">1914 translation by H. Rackham</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a></li>
                    
 </ul>
 
 
 
 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   
 
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap's js is handling the click action so you are not able to apply your custom effect you want. you need to do some tweeks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this? You searched for the wrong elements. I suggest taking a look at the jQuery API ;)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#accordion .panel').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".accordion-toggle .indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
    $(this).find(".panel-collapse").collapse("show");
  }, function() {
    var $collapse = $(this).find(".panel-collapse");
    $(this).find(".accordion-toggle .indicator").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $collapse.collapse("hide");
    },400);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">


      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Food <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <ul class="arrow cate list-unstyled">

          <li><a class="" href="#">1914 translation by H. Rackham</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--loop ends here-->


  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
          Tourist Spot <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">


        <ul class="arrow cate list-unstyled">

          <li><a class="" href="#">1914 translation by H. Rackham</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
         Weekend Gateway  <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <ul class="arrow cate list-unstyled">

          <li><a class="" href="#">1914 translation by H. Rackham</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem Lorem Ipsem</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is a little bit helping but the some problem still there on **mouseleave** its collapsed

Comment: @GautamJha I just fixed it :)

Comment: @GautamJha I see, the animation was running and it prevented the closing call. I added a delay which should fix it.

Comment: @GautamJha You're welcome. Did you see I modified your code and mine also changes the arrow? :)